# ImportError: No module named 'django_pandas'

Tags: python, django-pandas

I installed `numpy`, but when I install `django_pandas` it gives me an error:

> Using cached pandas-0.22.0.tar.gz
>     Could not find a version that satisfies the re
>   sions: 1.10.4, 1.11.0, 1.11.1rc1, 1.11.1, 1.11.2
>   .12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0, 1.12.1rc1, 1.12.1,
>   13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2)
>   No matching distribution found for numpy==1.9.3

Comment: Please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question accordingly.  This will help improve your chances of getting an answer, and also avoid having your question deleted.  Remember, everyone here is a volunteer : proof reading your post makes it easier for people to understand your question, and entices people to *want* to help.  Incorrect capitalization, spelling, and code/quote/text formatting signals that lack of effort, and lack of appreciation for would-be helpers.  I *do* wish you the best, in finding a solution :-)

Comment: Confusion: the error in your title does not match the error in the body of your question, or even the question itself.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and downgrading pip worked for me, like this:

```
pip install pip==9.0.1
```

After that I could install django-pandas normally.